# Ethernet not working after switching from Plusnet to Sky Broadband (Ubuntu Studio 18.04)

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet

Today I switched to a new broadband provider, installing their hub/modem in place of our previous supplier's. Everything is working fine (wi-fi, ethernet on Windows PCs) except the ethernet on my Ubuntu Studio 18.04 desktop. It worked fine previously but I'm assuming the change in network name has somehow messed things up (it's definitely not the cable as the same one works on a Windows PC).

The little connection icon just spins repeatedly "Requesting an ethernet network address for "Wired Connection 1". I plugged a wifi dongle in and that works alright.
I have no idea what to do here. I've tried a few things I've found online that might have been relevant but with no success ('ifplugd' made no difference).

If anyone has any ideas how I can solve this I'd be grateful as I prefer an ethernet cable and presume it must be something basic. **None of the hardware has changed, and neither did the software - it worked fine under Plusnet but can't seem to talk to Sky.**  I've been searching for solutions for a couple of hours with no success.

@heynnema solved, thanks for your help
@24601 solved, thanks for your help
@waltinator solved, thanks for your help

Comment: maybe a stupid question but have you rebooted or tried `network manager restart`?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and screenshots of your "Wired Connection 1" tabs. Is your ethernet cable plugged directly into the new broadband hub/modem? Who/what was your previous broadband provider? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's the right usage to answer your own question but I seem to have solved this problem. It was nothing to do with the software - I have two desktop PC's plugged into an ethernet splitter. I only ever have one switched on at a time, and it never created a problem with my previous modem, but clearly the Sky Hub doesn't like it. **Even if the second cable isn't plugged into anything**, if I add it to the splitter while either PC is on, the ethernet signal gets blocked. How the Sky Hub detects this is beyond me but hopefully this might be useful to anyone else running into the same (admittedly unusual) problem.

Thanks for your answers & time, much appreciated.

Comment: I'm seeing these messages pop up after setting up a bridget network connection under Virtual Machine Manager under Ubuntu 22.04 it may be related. You get a point.